# Getting financial data into data frames for multiple tickers

Tags: python, pandas, loops, finance, yfinance

here is the code :

```
**tickers = ['AMZN','AAPL','MSFT','DIS','GOOG']     
# Created individual dataframes for each category of data and tickers 
BS0=yfs.get_balance_sheet(tickers[0])
IS0=yfs.get_income_statement(tickers[0])
CF0=yfs.get_cash_flow(tickers[0])
BS0.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
IS0.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
CF0.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
BS0.columns.name = tickers[0]
IS0.columns.name = tickers[0]
CF0.columns.name = tickers[0]

BS1=yfs.get_balance_sheet(tickers[1])
IS1=yfs.get_income_statement(tickers[1])
CF1=yfs.get_cash_flow(tickers[1])
BS1.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
IS1.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
CF1.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
BS1.columns.name = tickers[1]
IS1.columns.name = tickers[1]
CF1.columns.name = tickers[1]

BS2=yfs.get_balance_sheet(tickers[2])
IS2=yfs.get_income_statement(tickers[2])
CF2=yfs.get_cash_flow(tickers[2])
BS2.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
IS2.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
CF2.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
BS2.columns.name = tickers[2]
IS2.columns.name = tickers[2]
CF2.columns.name = tickers[2]

BS3=yfs.get_balance_sheet(tickers[3])
IS3=yfs.get_income_statement(tickers[3])
CF3=yfs.get_cash_flow(tickers[3])
BS3.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
IS3.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
CF3.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
BS3.columns.name = tickers[3]
IS3.columns.name = tickers[3]
CF3.columns.name = tickers[3]

BS4=yfs.get_balance_sheet(tickers[4])
IS4=yfs.get_income_statement(tickers[4])
CF4=yfs.get_cash_flow(tickers[4])
BS4.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
IS4.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
CF4.columns = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']
BS4.columns.name = tickers[4]
IS4.columns.name = tickers[4]
CF4.columns.name = tickers[4]**
```

I have tried writing with **for ticker in tickers** logic and then converting to data frame with pandas, but this gives me a huge data frame with all the information packed into individual cells instead of columns and I have no idea how to spread it out in a way that makes sense for referencing.

Maybe there is a way to do this or simply to create a loop to save different data frames such as the code above but with less lines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try maintaining a dictionary of dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['AMZN','AAPL','MSFT','DIS','GOOG']
column_names = ['Period0','Period1','Period2','Period3']

ticker_dfs ={}

for index, ticker in enumerate(tickers):

    bs_index = 'BS' + str(index)
    is_index = 'IS' + str(index)
    cf_index = 'CF' + str(index)

    ticker_dfs[bs_index] = yfs.get_balance_sheet(ticker)
    ticker_dfs[bs_index].columns = column_names

    ticker_dfs[is_index] = yfs.get_income_statement(ticker)
    ticker_dfs[is_index].columns = column_names

    ticker_dfs[cf_index] = yfs.get_cash_flow(ticker)
    ticker_dfs[cf_index].columns = column_names
```

Comment: works perfectly ! same result with 3x less code ... will also be useful for longer lists.. thanks !!

Comment: as a note I added : ticker_dfs[xx_index].columns.name=ticker for each index so they are easily identified when calling them out individually